# google's use of class names

Tags: html, css

i noticed a very strange way of naming classes in G+ and gmail..

example: `a-b-h-Jb a-b-Rf-dB a-Rf-dB d-s-r` (see G+'s code for yourself!)

who the hell does that? impossible to keep track of what you did in future.. same for gmail.

it is a known way of doing css that i am unfamiliar with? is it OOCSS? if a googler is reading this, can you please explain? Or if you are not the one who wrote the code, then please share your thoughts or prove that i am a dumb ass and don't know about a fairly common css naming 'good practice' (can i even call it that?)

Comment: It's basically minification of the css class names, to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Google uses something called the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) (or simply GWT) to compile Java "applications" into their Javascript/HTML/CSS counterparts. GWT was used for GMail and Google Wave and my assumption is that it was also used for G+.

The GWT "compiler" (CS purists would never call GWT a compiler but the term fits) programatically names Javascript functions, CSS classes, HTML form IDs, etc. so they are almost never something legible.

Comment: oh yesm compilation makes sense.. but it is strange that the google devs are not really web devs they are java people :O is there a specific advantage of first writing code in java and then converting instead of writing straight? i know facebook does this too, with php and C

Comment: plus afaik, html/js/css are the future.. right? plus google is a huge advocate of new web technologies..

Comment: Writing everything with GWT cuts down in development time and cuts down on debugging time. As a simple example, GWT always compiles into code that will run equivalently on all browsers, even when dealing with finicky technologies such as AJAX.

Comment: so its basically write for one run on all.. sounds magical :P but thanks for the info, i knew about GWT but didn't really knew what it does.

Comment: Keep in mind that GWT is not a silver bullet, but it does help dev time quite a lot. The learning curve can be a bit daunting, however. Happy coding.

Comment: google did not use GWT :O http://www.anyasq.com/79-im-a-technical-lead-on-the-google+-team?answer_id=443

Comment: Is there by any chance a Grunt task that would do this same thing??

Comment: @Achshar, nobody in their right mind would write "straight" html and css and javascript. Everyone uses some helpers whether its libraries like jQuery or Bootstrap or transpilers like CoffeeScript or TypeScript. There are a lot of tools to get from some source to html/css/js and there is no one correct solution for all situations.

Answer (score 16):

At a guess, they probably have everything written out nicely in full at some point, and then put it through some program to compress it (reduce the length of variables). This reduces readability but also reduces file size, improving load times in theory.