# Converting css class names to random letters

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet, dynamic-css

I read stylesheets of facebook and Google and i noticed that class names used in css styles are some random letters and numbers? can we convert all css classes names to some random letters after developing web page? how they did it? is there any tool for doing this?

Comment: You can use find and replace tools of some ide like Dreamviewer, Zend Studio.

Comment: did u mean we have to find every class one by one and replace them with some letters? This is too long procedure.

Comment: Yes, you could. If you wanted to. Note that Facebook isn't using random class names, though. They're not terribly human-readable, but they are clearly not random and appear to be part of whatever particular CSS framework Facebook has created--likely one to go along with their back end framework as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer you're looking for is the same one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561683/2040509):

> Google uses something called the [Google Web Toolkit](http://www.gwtproject.org/?csw=1) (or simply
>   GWT) to compile Java "applications" into their Javascript/HTML/CSS
>   counterparts. GWT was used for GMail and Google Wave and my assumption
>   is that it was also used for G+.
>
> The GWT "compiler" (CS purists would never call GWT a compiler but the
>   term fits) programatically names Javascript functions, CSS classes,
>   HTML form IDs, etc. so they are almost never something legible.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up torque. :D