# how to change css class names on published site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, saas

I was inspecting the https://www.swiggy.com/bangalore/restaurants page with chrome developer tool. All the classes name in the site are uniquely converted like below:

```
.nDVxx ._3kbpE ._29C7I .pI5n2 ._13eJa ._3dU2z._1wKMm _2ntE2
```

How do they do it?
 what technology is this? 
and how it connects with actual CSS file where relevant names given.

Regards,
Gururaj

Comment: they use react and css module for that kind of classes

Comment: This might prove useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952024/converting-css-class-names-to-random-letters