# tools for obfuscating html and css

Tags: html, css, obfuscation, minify

I am looking for something like [this](https://github.com/ccampbell/html-muncher) or [this](http://htmlmuncher.com/)

what it does

> rewrites classes and ids in CSS, HTML, and JavaScript files, 
>   doing something like .class to .a or #id to #a not sure the javascript obfu is great to use ( i prefer google closure to do this ) but the html and css is the question.

is there any alternative ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use that one?

Comment: Probably because their logo is terribad.

Comment: @wsanville lol near right, but the truth is that im looking for an active development so i can hop in, i really want to see if there is any more active projects slimier then this.

Comment: @AdamRamadhan did you have any luck finding an alternative?

Comment: HTML Tidy is a good alternative http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: try this: [https://github.com/bitstrider/obscure](https://github.com/bitstrider/obscure)

Answer (score 9):

Google's [Closure Stylesheets](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/) can rename your class names. It work in conjunction with [Closure Template](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/) for the HTML and [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) for the JavaScript.

> Closure Stylesheets makes it possible to rename CSS class names in the generated stylesheet, which helps reduce the size of the CSS that is sent down to your users. Of course, this is not particularly useful unless the class names are renamed consistently in the HTML and JavaScript files that use the CSS. Fortunately, you can use the Closure Compiler to update the class names in your JavaScript and Closure Templates to update the class names in your HTML.

Comment: the problem about google closure is i dont know where to start using, im looking for something like `example --html=myhtml.html --css=css.css --output /folder`

Answer (score 4):

I saw [html muncher](http://htmlmuncher.com/) mentioned in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6602698).  I have not tried it, but it looks to be as simple to use as what you mentioned in your comment on Jerome's answer.  It doesn't look to be actively maintained though.

[Update] I also found a similar node project, [munch.js](http://jmrocela.github.io/munchjs/), that says it is based on html muncher.