# using import url will it protect my css code

Tags: css, stylesheet

I've been target for someone used to copy my website style sheet so this time i would like to protect my css file using the following :-

i will create `fake.css` and inside it will put the following code based on `@import url`

```
@import url("css/real.css");
```

Now if he view source will only see the above line and will try to call

```
www.my_site.com/css/real.css
```

but i will indeed using my hosting panel will not allow direct access to files `.css`

Now my question, Is it save enough or still he can get the code by using firebug or whatever !? ~ thanks

Comment: They will be able to get it using firebug or inspecting the element. If you don't want your CSS to be seen, don't put it on the internet.

Comment: or create old-school website without CSS ;-)

Comment: all right thank you all, it was just thoughts into my mind :) cause i've had enough of someone copy/paste my website

Comment: There's nothing you can do to completely stop someone from copying your styles. The best I can think of is something like obfuscating your HTML/CSS/JS, but that would at best slow them down if they are trying to cherry pick stuff. It might be hindering enough to make them target some other site? Related to obfuscation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278863/tools-for-obfuscating-html-and-css

Comment: @jeromeM The style attribute is so tempting, eh? ;)

Comment: You could put half of your rules in imported CSS and the other half in the "parent" CSS file to make their copy failure less obvious but that would cause an extra hit for every user and would only prevent noobs from stealing your code. If their server is in the US, you could send a DMCA takedown notice (IANAL and that must be a boring activity ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to hide CSS from your users.