# How to Create hidden CSS?

Tags: asp.net, css, frame, hidden

how can I design CSS (specially in asp.net) which user could not save that in client side? I do not want to use from flash or other embedded technology. only frame and css.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. CSS is telling the browser how an element is supposed to look, making it so a user can't save/understand it would mean the browser wouldn't know how to read it. If you want to obfuscate the css you can check this >> [tools for obfuscating html and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278863/tools-for-obfuscating-html-and-css)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really prevent the user from downloading the css. The browser needs HTML and CSS to render the page correctly to the user. So the browser actually queries for the HTML and CSS files from server and loads it.

Also you cannot obfuscate CSS files as browsers cant understand those lines.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility, only obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible.  Modern browsers will even show the cascade, rules, etc. that apply to an element in a developer console.  Google Chrome for example, has this.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all answer. that was useful. but why we can not save complete gmail.com or mail.yahoo.com?
I think they use flash or silver or ....