# Restricting access to static files using Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I am creating a web application using the bottle framework. Since we need to provide routes to static files such as:

```
  def server_css(self, filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='css')
```

Is there any way from restricting a user in just typing /css/file.css to access the file?

Comment: Do you mean like by putting an authentication?

Comment: yes, the script should be able to access it, but not anyone else

Comment: you mean, you want the html to be able to use it, but no one to be able to download it?  why?  that's not really sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

I mean, you could come up with some elaborate, obfuscated dynamic (javascript) loading mechanism, but is it really worth it?

But you could put your sensitive files in a different, protected, location.  So there'd be `/css/file.css`, which would be publicly accessible.  Then there'd be `/private/file.txt` which you'd protect with your favorite flavor of authentication.

---

If this is specifically about hiding your css from the general public, I suppose you could try to obfuscate it, but IMO that's a bit of [a fool's errand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597914/minifying-and-obsfucating-css-similar-to-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check an href http headers. They might be empty when user types in browser and something otherwise.

Comment: I think you mean Referer header.  (And no, that's not a good idea.)